# Track users that visit your Instagram profile

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

is there a way I can use the instagram API and check what users are visiting my instagram profile ?

For example, I'd like to develop something that tells you what users are visiting your profile the most on a weekly basis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it might be possible now with the facebook insight graph API. It's basicly a new one where you can find data connection between facebook and instagram accounts. Mainly targeting business account thought.